# How to reduce the size of SVG file for Cricut

Tags: svg, file-size

I have several designs created for graphic T-shirts. Due to the size of each file, the error message reads, "File Too Large". I have tried reducing the size in Adobe Illustrator using the rastersize feature but haven't been successful. The file sizes range from 1.8 to 2.9 MB. They need to be sized to KB. What is a simplistic way to shrink the file size?

Comment: Does the SVG contain raster images, or is it just all outlines? Are there a lot of paths and anchors/nodes in the SVG?  Are you sure the error message is that the file size is too big, and not just [the size of the image](https://help.cricut.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009429814-Design-Space-says-printable-image-is-too-large) that is too big? This is difficult to answer without access to the actual SVG file. Also note that tech support questions are generaly off-topic here. Perhaps the [Cricut help site](https://help.cricut.com/hc/en-us) would be the best place to get tech support.

Comment: I tried to actually post the image with my question but, of course, it says that the file is too large. Can I show it to you another way? maybe via email? I have even tried reducing them in inkscape as well.

Comment: You could try SVGshare. It's free, no login is required. But tech support is still off-topic. I could have a look at it, but can't promise anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the file as an SVG, not rasterize. Rasterizing creates a much larger file; SVGs are really just text and are very small.

I've used very complex designs with Cricut Design Space without any problems. If you can share one of your files, I can take a look at what's going on with it.

(I know this is an old post but I have a lot of Cricut experience and am happy to help!)